# SQL Server 2008 - update table A using results of join B with C

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I tried searching before posting this question, but was not able to find another example.

I am painfully aware that SQL is currently my Achilles' heel and am working on it, so please bear with me!

My tale of woe concerns 3 tables:

tableA: has the column (estId) I wish to update

tableB: contains establishment details, including name (estName)

tableC: contains establishment data to be imported, including establishment name (estName) and associated establishment id (estCode)

In pseudo language, what I wish to achieve is:

```
Update tableA
Set estId = tableC.estCode
Where tableC.estName = tableB.estName
```

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET estId = tableC.estCode
FROM
    tableC
    JOIN tableB
    ON tableC.estName = tableB.estName
```

That failed. Or rather, it updated the estId column, but each row contained the first value from tableC.

I am probably missing something obvious ...

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to join TableA to other tables in `from` clause. I don't see the connection from the info above. So, `update TableA set estId = tableC.estCode from TableA inner join TableB on ... inner join TableC ...`

Comment: You need a condition to join onto tableA - otherwise the database engine doesn't know how to update the columns. What other columns are there in tableA that correspond to columns in tableB or tableC?

Comment: Something to start with: your current join/update doesnt have any condition on tableA. How do you expect to match between the rows from tableB/tableC and the rows you want to update in tableA?

Comment: Thanks all - I knew it would be something fairly obvious. Before attempting the above, I tried a SELECT query to see if it returned the results I wanted. The problem here is my lack of knowledge - I simply did not know how to properly construct the UPDATE with the JOIN

Comment: Just to clarify: is the question resolved?

Comment: Yes Andriy, it is resolved. I cannot see how to mark it as resolved, because all answers were posted as comments.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE t_alias
SET t_alias.estId = tableC.estCode
FROM
    tableA as t_alias
    JOIN tableB on 
        tableB.estID = tableA.estID
    JOIN tableC
    ON tableC.estName = tableB.estName